# Circular attributes in Python

Tags: python, class, attributes, circular-dependency

I am working with several classes, with each having it's own attributes.
Trying to avoid to pass a lot of variables when calling sub_functions, I would rather call classe's attributes.

As an example, let's concider 2 classes such as :

```
class Class_A(object):
   def __init__(self, element_b):
      self.value_specific_to_a = 1
      self.element_b = element_b

   def element_a_can_do(self):
      print(self.element_b.value_specific_to_b)
```

```
class Class_B(object):
   def __init__(self):
      self.element_a = None
      self.value_specific_to_b = 2

   def add_a(self, element_a):
      self.element_a = element_a

   def element_b_can_do(self):
      print(self.element_a.value_specific_to_a)
```

```
item_b = Class_B()
item_a = Class_A(item_b)

item_b.add_a(item_a)
```

I think that it is pointer's addresses of those classes that are save to each other, but I wonder if it can cause any issue/leak in my code.

Comment: What you have is probably fine. The only question might be, do you want `item_b.element_a` to keep the instance of `Class_A` alive after, say, `del item_a`? If not, you might want to use a weak reference inside `Class_B`.

Comment: If *both* `item_a` and `item_b` are deleted, then the otherwise orphaned instances do keep each other alive, but Python's garbage collector is designed to find such reference cycles and would collect both objects in that case.